# What data structure OS uses to know how much free memory is left?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

> How our operating system maintains memory i.e., which of the memory blocks are free and which are not?For e.g.,

```
int a;
```

> How OS figure out which memory is to be assigned to 'a' variable?

Answer (score 0):

I must point out that this is operating system specific. But usually, all modern operating systems uses a technique called paging to implement virtual memory. Processes have linear virtual address space where only pages (of fixed size) gets mapped to real physical memory (a.k.a working set). So, technically, the OS keeps track of memory free space in terms of availabale free page frames (in RAM) that could be used to map virtual address spaces of different active processes. One approach to keep a list of all the free pages is using a linked list from which you allocate new page frames or insert pages that have been freed.
**EDIT** : The same technique of linked list could be used to manage dynamic memory in the virtual address space ( Think `malloc` of `Libc`).